# Why the published conferences dont appear?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query below to get the published conferences:

```
$publishedConferences =
            $user->conferences()->
            where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', '=', 'P');
                $query->where('end_date','>', now());
            })
                ->paginate($pageLimit);

        dd($publishedConferences);
```

But $publishedConferences shows:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#345 ▼
  #total: 1
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#344 ▶}
  #perPage: 5
  #currentPage: 2
  #path: "https://proj.test/user/profile"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

And so no conference appears. However in database there is a conference  where the status is equal "P" and where "end_date" is ">now()".

Do you know what can be the issue?

HTML where the published conferences appear:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show clearfix" id="publishedConferences" role="tabpanel"
 aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($publishedConferences as $publishedConference)
            @if(!empty($publishedConference))
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <p>{{$publishedConference->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                    <h5>{{$publishedConference->name}}</h5>
                </li>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
        {{$publishedConferences->fragment('publishedConferences')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the where clause to:

```
 // or toDateTimeString() if needed for datetime type column
 $query->where('end_date','>', now()->toDateString());
```